# Tree Structure Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, query-optimization

Using Azure SQL Server, I have a table that store an organization's tree structure in a single table that looks like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserManagement_GroupDef]
    (
        [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [PortalId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [GroupType] [int] NOT NULL,
        [ParentGroupId] [bigint] NULL,
        [GroupName] [nvarchar](2048) NOT NULL,
        [IsDefault] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
        [PhoneNumber] [varchar](10) NULL,
        [UserManagementId] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
        [Address] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
        [Suite] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
        [City] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
        [State] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
        [Position] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
        [Zip] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
        [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_UserManagement_GroupDef] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED     
   (
    [ID] ASC
   )WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

All columns are indexed.

`[ParentGroupId]` references another row in the same table. The table, all in all, represents a tree structure.

In the query, below, I am attempting to find all descendent children of group `ID 155`.

```
WITH tblChild AS
    (
        SELECT 
        ID
        ,ParentGroupId
        ,[IsDeleted]
        ,[PortalId]
        ,[GroupType]
        ,[GroupName]
        ,[IsDefault]
        ,[Email]
        ,[PhoneNumber]
        ,[UserManagementId]
        ,[Address]
        ,[Suite]
        ,[City]
        ,[State]
        ,[Position]
        ,[Zip]
            FROM UserManagement_GroupDef    
            WHERE ID = 155 AND IsDeleted = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
             UserManagement_GroupDef.ID,
             UserManagement_GroupDef.ParentGroupId, 
             UserManagement_GroupDef.[IsDeleted],
             UserManagement_GroupDef.[PortalId],
             UserManagement_GroupDef.[GroupType],
             UserManagement_GroupDef.[GroupName],
             UserManagement_GroupDef.[IsDefault],
             UserManagement_GroupDef.[Email],
             UserManagement_GroupDef.[PhoneNumber],
             UserManagement_GroupDef.[UserManagementId],
             UserManagement_GroupDef.[Address],
             UserManagement_GroupDef.[Suite],
             UserManagement_GroupDef.[City],
             UserManagement_GroupDef.[State],
             UserManagement_GroupDef.[Position],
             UserManagement_GroupDef.[Zip]

        FROM UserManagement_GroupDef  
        JOIN 
            tblChild  
                ON 
                    UserManagement_GroupDef.ParentGroupId = tblChild.ID
                WHERE tblChild.IsDeleted = 0        
    )

    SELECT 
            tblChild.ID,
             tblChild.ParentGroupId, 
             tblChild.[IsDeleted],
             tblChild.[PortalId],
             tblChild.[GroupType],
             tblChild.[GroupName],
             tblChild.[IsDefault],
             tblChild.[Email],
             tblChild.[PhoneNumber],
             tblChild.[UserManagementId],
             tblChild.[Address],
             tblChild.[Suite],
             tblChild.[City],
             tblChild.[State],
             tblChild.[Position],
             tblChild.[Zip]
        FROM tblChild
```

The table currently has just under 7000 records. This particular query returns a result with just under 2000 rows. The result is ultimately correct but takes ~20 seconds to execute.

Is there a way to speed this query up or to achieve the same result, only faster?

Execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1k0Qdrzd

Table Indices:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserManagement_GroupDef] ON [dbo].[UserManagement_GroupDef]
(
    [IsDeleted] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserManagement_GroupDef_2] ON [dbo].[UserManagement_GroupDef]
(
    [ParentGroupId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserManagement_GroupDef_3] ON [dbo].[UserManagement_GroupDef]
(
    [IsDeleted] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [umg_query_index] ON [dbo].[UserManagement_GroupDef]
(
    [ParentGroupId] ASC
)
INCLUDE(

[ID],
[IsDeleted],
[PortalId],
[GroupType],
[GroupName],
[IsDefault],
[Email],
[PhoneNumber],
[UserManagementId],
[Address],
[Suite],
[City],
[State],
[Position],
[Zip]
)

WHERE ([IsDeleted]=(0))

WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Why are you using BIGINT for 7k records? What kind of indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: I recently came up with a new way to manage hierarchal data in SQL which will speed things up. If I can find time I'll post an example. https://codingblackarts.com/2021/02/09/virtual-indexing-part-9-the-indexed-hierarchy/

Comment: I suggest you push the `IsDeleted` predicate to the inside of the CTE. A filtered index `ParentGroupId WHERE IsDeleted = 0` is probably very helpful. Please [edit] your question including **all** index definitions. Please also share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com

Comment: Yeah definitely push the predicate into the recursive part of the CTE, then it will use your new index `umg_query_index`

Comment: @Charlieface you want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what is going on is that **the compiler is not able to push down** the outer predicate `IsDeleted = 0` into the CTE. It therefore cannot use the `umg_query_index` as recommended by [O. Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66357207/14868997).

**Why that is the case,** is because each run of the recursive section could return rows which are `IsDeleted = 1`, which need to feed back into the next run. While it is true that they do *not* appear in the final result, it is still possible that such a row may have child rows that *do* need to appear in the final resultset. So there is no way to eliminate them from the recursive join.

You have two options:

1. Change your `IX_UserManagement_GroupDef_2` index, so that it also contains the `IsDeleted` column, it does not need to be in the key, it can be an `INCLUDE`:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserManagement_GroupDef_2] ON [dbo].[UserManagement_GroupDef]
([ParentGroupId] ASC) INCLUDE (IsDeleted)
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

2. Probably the better option, **push down the predicate yourself.** Then it will use O. Jones' index on both parts of the CTE.

```sql
WITH tblChild AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM UserManagement_GroupDef 
    WHERE ID = 155 AND IsDeleted = 0                

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        u.* 
    FROM 
        UserManagement_GroupDef u
    JOIN 
        tblChild ON u.ParentGroupId = tblChild.ID
    WHERE u.IsDeleted = 0
)
SELECT *
FROM tblChild
```

This query **has different semantics** from your original one. It will not return any rows for which the parent is `IsDeleted = 1`.

At this point you could also change your new index to be a filtered one, as this means any `IsDeleted` rows will not be stored.

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX umg_query_index ON UserManagement_GroupDef
(ParentGroupId)  INCLUDE (IsDeleted) WHERE IsDeleted = 0
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = ON) ON [PRIMARY];
```

You must include the `IsDeleted` column in the index, otherwise the optimizer may fail to use it, due to faulty logic as currently implemented.

---

**One further note:** single-column indexes are not usually that useful and should generally be avoided. It is not worth it for the server to try union two indexes together, it will scan the clustered index instead.

I suggest you drop the indexes `IX_UserManagement_GroupDef` and `IX_UserManagement_GroupDef_3` as they are now completely superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  Unfortunately I saw zero change in execution time.  In fact, if I completely remove all predicates related to IsDeleted and only have the "ID = 155" predicate, the execution is nearly identical.

Comment: Can you share the query plans for both of those versions via https://pastetheplan.com?

Comment: iS that the same as https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ ?  pastetheplan.com isn't pulling up for me.

Comment: Yeah it's the same

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkbzQPHzO  and  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkkbEwHG_  Thanks!

Comment: OK you're selecting a bazillion other columns, your table has far more columns than what you said. You should have the index (whichever you want to use depending on the query) `INCLUDE` every one of those columns. I suggest you think about which columns you need and remove the others, see [Bad Habits to Kick : Using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). **In future remember, on [so] we can only help you if you give us the correct info**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was trying to omit what I thought was superfluous.  I've updated my question with more complete table def data, query and index as you suggested. At this time, I am operating under the assumption that I do need all 15 columns.  Updated plan at  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1k0Qdrzd .  Thanks for your help. I'm learning today!

Comment: As you can see, you still have that Clustered Index Scan. It's not using the `ParentGroup` index because it has a `WHERE` filter and your current query does not. Either remove the filter on the index, or change your query back to exclude `IsDeleted` rows

Comment: You totally saved me!  I'm not a DBA, but I learned a lot about indexes today.  Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE INDEX umg_query_index ON UserManagement_GroupDef (IsDeleted, ParentGroupId);
```

Better yet, run the query in SSMS. Before you run it, right click in the query window and enable Show Actual Execution Plan.

Then look at the execution plan. It probably will recommend the right index for you.